# Hadoop datatype for Cloudera exam

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Greeting Gurus

How do I learn about Hadoop datatype..read doc..?
Some sample questions from cloudera exam:

**Question 2**

You need to write code to perform a complex calculation that takes several steps. You have decided to chain these jobs together and develop a custom composite class for the key that stores the results of intermediate calculations. Which interface must this key implement?
A. Writable
B. Transferable
C. CompositeSortable
D. WritableComparable

```
I say is D. WritableComparable
```

**Question 3**

You are developing an application that uses a year for the key. Which Hadoop-supplied data type would be most appropriate for a key that represents a year?
A. Text
B. IntWritable
C. NullWritable
D. BytesWritable
E. None of these would be appropriate. You would need to implement a custom key.

```
I say is E
```

Comment: Please don't format your text as code, neither format the question as code. Thanks. Also years (e.g. 2010) can be expressed by an integer (with vint compression), the byte type isn't in range here.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: D. WritableComparable - correct
Q2: B. IntWritable as year is always an integer that would fit in integer field. You can probably use any of A, B, D & E but B is easiest/efficient and hence most appropriate.

Comment: What is a good resource for studying the data type for hadoop like use cases as such ?

Comment: There are books like Definitive Guide , Hadoop in Action etc. But atleast you may want to go to Apache website and start reading.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 Answer is D, because you need to serialize and deserialize the values. Writablecomparable is required  only for secondary sorting. that is not required here
Q2.Year needs to be Text as we are not computing anything with that. it is just passed as a Key.